Renault Master 3, vehicle speed CAN ID message?
I am tapping the CAN BUS of Renault Master 3 2024 with PCAN-USB FD. I get many messages, however I am not able to figure out which one shows the vehicle/wheel speed.
Does any of you knows the exact message that displays speed of the vehicle or has any idea where I can find it? Probably some dbc file of Renault master would do the job?
